# Does Yocto Linux load manage the cores?

Tags: linux, yocto, load

Does Yocto Linux load manage the cores on a multiple core CPU? Tried looking for info on forums, etc. Can't find a definite answer. Thanks!

Comment: there has to be _some_ scheduler, do you have reason to suspect it would be different from the kernel's default?

Comment: Your question is not clear: I have read it 3 times, and have 3 different interpretations. Edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Fox, we're moving our dev from RTOS to Linux Embedded.  One of my task is to determine if Yocto Linux manages the cores on a dual-core processor.  Would run multiple applications and use both core for efficient processing?  Or do we need to assign applications on one core and others on another?  Thank you!

Comment: ctrl-alt-delor, if I my target hardware is a dual-core CPU, will Yocto use both cores?  Or do I need to do the core management myself?  Thank you!